# Assigning shorcuts to macros through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently working with 50+ files and have to add the same module to each of them and I'm trying to do so with a program rather than manually.

One of the problems I've encountered is that the macro that I'm adding to the files should be run through a keyboard shortcut, and to add that in Word, you have to go all the way into customize ribbon and assigning it. For 50+ files it's rather tedious to do for each file and I've tried to write a snippet that assigns it for me instead.

```
Sub AssignShortcut()
    ' Assign Shift+F1 as a shortcut for a macro
    With Application
        .CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
        .KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyShift, wdKeyF1), _
            KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="BeregnKoter.main"
    End With
End Sub
```

The weird thing is that this does work *once*. If I manually go and delete the shortcut and try to reassign it with the code, it results in the code running but doing absolutely nothing.

I've tried to clear all keybindings to see if that helped, but still nothing.

Code used to clear keybindings:

```
Sub ClearExistingShortcuts()
    ' Set the customization context to the Normal template
    Application.CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate

    ' Clear all existing key bindings in the Normal template
    Application.KeyBindings.ClearAll
End Sub
```

If I only remove the keybinds through the ClearExistingShortcuts() and not manually I can reassign the keybind just fine.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: I could not reproduce this here, but I did not a few anomalies while investigating. Could be a problem in my installation(s). Also, I wonder if having multiple instances of Word might modify the behaviour. e.g. if I create a keybinding in NormalTemplate, then delete it manually in the UI, it actually removes the binding completely. The macro recorded by Word uses the Keybinding's .Disable method. But if I use that method programmatically, it does not delete the Binding - in effect, it blanks out the Keybinding's .Command text...

Comment: ...if I try the same thing but with a keybinding stored in a document, manual "Remove" in the UI just blanks out the KeyBinding's commend string, same as programmatically using .Disable. Finally, in Mac Word I found that for one KeyBinding, both .Clear and .ClearAll removed the KeyBinding, but if I had used the shift-F1 key before the .Clear/.ClearAll, the shift-F1 key still invoked the BeregnKoter.main macro (until I closed/re-opened the document or Word, I think .

Comment: Turns out that I'm just an idiot. Both macros were in Project as they should be but I'm using the NormalTemplate as the CustomizationContext where I should obviously have used ActiveDocument instead. It now works as intended.